# Visual Studio scratch disk behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diskspace, filesize

I don't know if this feature exists, but I'd like a way to control Visual Studio 2010's scratch disk behavior (other than completely turning off intellisense).

Right now it creates a massive .sdf file in the project folder (50MB+), and then it goes and creates an IPCH folder with 60MB+ of precompiled headers.

All that's well and good while VS is running, but after it exits, I really would like the disk back.

Is there a way to configure vs 2010 to

1. Use the *same* location (%AppData%\VSScratch) for scratch disk files (so its easier to blow it away?)
2. Automatically delete .sdf /ipch on exit?

I know they don't delete them because its faster to startup.. but if you delete them yourself, startup time isn't *that much* increased..

Comment: With a terabyte of disk space selling for less than a hundred bucks, this is not something you should every have to fuzz with.  Your time is much too valuable.

Comment: Oh but, I do.  Its not only the disk space, its backing up the entire folder takes eons longer than it should if these temp files were removed, prior to backup.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out yet, but what you can do is go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced

then under that you can either completely disable the database or alternatively move it to a different location such as C:\VSdatabaseCrap\  ie: the fallback folder
This means your database files will still exist and take up diskspace, but the individual folder project folder will be MUCH smaller. This is useful for backing up to services like Dropbox, where you really don't care about your 200mb intellesense database.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx